# Is there a way to upload an image(.heic) file on my Wysiwyg editor without any image convertings?

Tags: javascript, html, image, wysiwyg, heic

I have created a rich text editor with javascript.
It accepts all image files except .heic images.

Is there a way to show heic images on my editor first and then upload it?

```js
const input = this.imageInput = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.accept = "image/*";
input.accept = ".heic";
input.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: It's not supported by any browser https://caniuse.com/#search=heif

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*, .heic">
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.